# NestJS e2e tests cannot find module with absolute path

Tags: nestjs, e2e-testing, ts-jest, nestjs-testing

When I run e2e test in my application with the command:
`jest --no-cache --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --detectOpenHandles`

I receive some errors like:

```
Cannot find module 'src/modules/shared/shared.module' from '../src/modules/charge/invoice/invoice.module.ts'
```

But it works if I change the path import to ../../src/ instead of only src/ in these other files.

jest-e2e.json

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "verbose": true
}
```

package.json

```
"version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
}
```

I tried to change the configuration files but without success (added "type": "module" in package.json; "include": ["src/**/*"] in tsconfig.json).
And saw similar questions but none work it.
I needed that src/ imports work too.